# PHP Form processing not send proper email

Tags: php, mysql, forms

I have the follwing form which is being populated via autosuggest from a database

```
<table class="table table-striped" id="itemsTable">
                <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th></th>
                    <th>Item Code</th>
                    <th>Description</th>
                    <th>Qty</th>
                    <th>Price</th>
                    <th>Total</th>
                </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                <tr class="item-row">
                    <td></td>
                    <form id="itemsForm" action="services/processOrder.php" method="post">
                    <td><input type="text" name="itemCode[]" value="" class="input-medium" id="itemCode"
                               tabindex="1"/>
                    </td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="itemDesc[]" value="" class="input-large" id="itemDesc"
                               readonly="readonly"/></td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="itemQty[]" value="" class="input-mini" id="itemQty" tabindex="2"/>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <div class="input-prepend input-append"><span class="add-on">&#8364;</span>
                        <input
                                name="itemPrice[]"
                                class=" input-small"
                                id="itemPrice"
                                type="text"></div>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <div class="input-prepend input-append"><span class="add-on">&#8364;</span><input
                                name="itemLineTotal[]" class=" input-small" id="itemLineTotal" type="text"
                                readonly="readonly"></div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
```

**and here is the php query for the autosuggest:**

```
<?php

require_once('db_connection.php');
$return_arr = array();

$param = $_GET["term"];

$query = "SELECT field_id_5, exp_weblog_titles.title, field_id_57  
          FROM exp_weblog_data, exp_weblog_titles 
          WHERE exp_weblog_titles.entry_id = exp_weblog_data.entry_id AND field_id_5
          LIKE '%". $param ."%'
          LIMIT 10";
$result = $mysqli->query($query) or die($mysqli->error.__LINE__);

/* Retrieve and store in array the results of the query.*/
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

    $row_array['jItemCode']        = $row['field_id_5'];
    $row_array['jItemDesc']        = $row['title'];
    $row_array['jItemPrice']       = $row['field_id_57'];
    //$row_array['jItemWholesale']        = $row['itemWholesale'];
    //$row_array['jItemRetail']           = $row['itemRetail'];
   // $row_array['jQtyOnHand']            = $row['qtyOnHand'];

    array_push( $return_arr, $row_array );
}


$result->free_result();
$mysqli->close();

/* Toss back results as json encoded array. */
echo json_encode($return_arr);
```

Finally here is the php for send the form as an email:

```
    <?php 
 $headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
 $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
 $headers .= "From: " . $_REQUEST['repName'] . ">\r\n";

 $to = 'dominic.mcafee@pmcnttyyre.com'; 
 $subject = "Web Contact Data"; 

 $fields = array(); 
 $fields{"itemCode[]"} = "Code"; 
 $fields{"itemDesc[]"} = "Description"; 
 $fields{"itemPrice[]"} = "Price"; 

 $body = "We have received the following information:\n\n"; 

 foreach($fields as $a => $b){
    $body .= sprintf("%20s: %s\n",$b,$_REQUEST[$a]); 
 } 

 $headers2 = "From: noreply@example.com"; 
 $subject2 = "Thank you for contacting us"; 
 $autoreply = "Thank you for contacting us. Somebody will get back to you as soon as possible, usualy within 48 hours. If you have any more questions, please consult our website at www.oursite.com";


 $send = mail($to, $subject, $body); 
 if($send){
    header( "Location:index.php" );
    } else {
        print "We encountered an error sending your mail, please try again"; 
    } 
?>
```

All I get in the email is "We have recieved the following information:
Code:
Description:
Price:
"

Please can someone help me out.  Where am I going wrong. I know Im close and the problem lies somewhere in referencing the array of data that is in the form.

Comment: `$_REQUEST[$a]`? I'm no PHP expert but that doesn't look right. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: The reason you are only showing 'Code, Description, Price' is because that is the only thing you're doing inside your loop. You're just looping through the 'fields' array, you're not looping through each $_POST request.

Answer (score 0):

Hard to say from code, but main reason is that $_REQUEST[$a] is empty. So try to echo whole $_REQUEST right after submitting your form for better debugging.

Also I dont see submit button and also end of the form tag - it could be bug too.